# Get the execution time of a ADO.NET SQL Command

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, ado.net

I have been searching over to find if there is any easy way to get the Execution time of a ADO.NET command object.

I know i can manually do a StopWatch start and stop. But wanted to if there are any easy way to do it in ADO.NET

Comment: Do you want just the execution time of the query, or the entire time including the time it took to get the data back to c#?

Comment: What are you trying to do? SQL Server already allows you to collect such data through Extended Events with minimal cost. Collecting statistics for individual queries can be interesting but not very useful for performance monitoring or troubleshooting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way, but using `SqlConnection`, not command object. Example:

```
using (var c = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    // important
    c.StatisticsEnabled = true;
    c.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Error", c)) {
        cmd.ExecuteReader().Dispose();
    }       
    var stats = c.RetrieveStatistics();
    var firstCommandExecutionTimeInMs = (long) stats["ExecutionTime"];
    // reset for next command
    c.ResetStatistics();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Code", c))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteReader().Dispose();
    }
    stats = c.RetrieveStatistics();
    var secondCommandExecutionTimeInMs = (long)stats["ExecutionTime"];
 }
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h2ahss8(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find what other values are contained inside dictionary returned by `RetrieveStatistics`.

Note that those values represent **client-side** statistics (basically internals of ADO.NET measure them), but seems you asked for analog of `Stopwatch` - I think that's fine.

Answer (score 5):

The approach from the [answer of @Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971290/6996876) is very interesting and smart: it's working **client** side and one of the main key of such statistics is in fact `NetworkServerTime`, which

> Returns the cumulative amount of time (in milliseconds) that the
>   provider spent waiting for replies from the server once the
>   application has started using the provider and has enabled statistics.

so it includes the network time from the DB server to the ADO NET client.

An alternative, more DB **server** oriented, would be running `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and then retrieve the `InfoMessage`.

A draft of the code of the delegate (where I'm simply writing to the debug console, but you may want to replace it with a `StringBuilder` `Append`)

```
internal static void TrackInfo(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    foreach (var element in e.Errors) {
        Debug.WriteLine(element.ToString());
    }
}
```

and usage

```
conn.InfoMessage +=  TrackInfo;
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SET STATISTICS TIME ON", conn)) {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(yourQuery, conn)) {
    var RD = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (RD.Read()) {
        // read the columns
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that's what the `StatisticsEnabled` switch does too? Return *server-side* statistics?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, in fact I've copied the definition of one of the key to show the difference, same thing if you look at `ExecutionTime`... The statistics in the other answer are client (meaning the ADO.NET provider) side

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes those are client-side statistics. Author asked for analog of measuring manually with `Stopwatch` so seems fit.

Comment: On the server, I'd use Extended Events and set it to collect performance stats from *all* queries. The cost is minimal (unlike the older Profiler) and the storage target can be in-memory or a file. One can add filter criteria like duration and IO to capture only specific events, eg frequent slow queries, infrequent heavy queries.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you move to SQL Server 2016 and use the [Query Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817826.aspx) feature. This will track execution time and performance changes over time for each query you submit. Requires no changes in your application. Track *all* queries, including those executed inside stored procedures. Track *any* application, not only your own. Is available in all editions, including Express, and including the Azure SQL DB Service.

If you track on the client side, you *must* measure the time yourself, using a wall clock. I would add and expose [performance counters](http://rusanu.com/2009/04/11/using-xslt-to-generate-performance-counters-code/) and then use the performance counters infrastructure to capture and store the measurements.

As a side not, simply tracking the execution time of a batch sent to SQL Server yields very coarse performance info and is seldom actionable. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Comment: That's not *easier* than simply retrieving the statistics of an execution.

Comment: Furthermore, you can get such statistics already using Extended Events and DMVs. Collecting and measuring performance can be performed with SQL Server Utility or Management Warehouse.  Query Store servers a different purpose.